# Environment has JRE 7 but getting Unsupported major.minor version 51.0

Tags: java, hadoop, java-7, unsupported-class-version

I am working on a Hadoop project which is deployed in test and production environments. While everything works fine in the test environment, the same code / build fails in the production environment with the below error :

> **Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/package/vo/MyClassName : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0**
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)   at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)   at
>   java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
>     at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)     at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)     at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)     at
>   java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)   at
>   java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247)   at
>   sun.reflect.generics.factory.CoreReflectionFactory.makeNamedType(CoreReflectionFactory.java:95)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitClassTypeSignature(Reifier.java:107)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.generics.tree.ClassTypeSignature.accept(ClassTypeSignature.java:31)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.reifyTypeArguments(Reifier.java:50)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitClassTypeSignature(Reifier.java:120)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.generics.tree.ClassTypeSignature.accept(ClassTypeSignature.java:31)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.generics.repository.FieldRepository.getGenericType(FieldRepository.java:67)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Field.getGenericType(Field.java:223)   at
>   com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:117)
>     at
>   com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:72)
>     at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:356)   at
>   com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:802)  at
>   com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:768)  at
>   com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:717)  at
>   com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:689)

I understand this should be due to version mismatch between java version used while compiling the class and java version used to run the same.

But I check this and see both my test and production environments use jre 7 and I believe version 51 should be compatible with this.

**Test environment**

```
]$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_79"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_79-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.79-b02, mixed mode)
```

**Production environment**

```
]$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_79"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_79-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.79-b02, mixed mode)
```

Hadoop version used in test environment : Hadoop 2.6.0.2.2.9.0-3393
Hadoop version used in production environment : Hadoop 2.4.0.2.1.15.3-7

The above class is run using the below command in a shell script  and this is where the error occurs.

```
**java -cp $ALL_JARS com.package.hello.hadoop.udf.GetCount**
```

where ALL_JARS is a ':' delimited list of jar files, one of which contains the above class GetCount and another contains the class for which the error is shown : com/package/vo/MyClassName

May I know what could be going wrong here and that too only in the production environment which also has the same java version as the test environment

Comment: Does the shell script modify the path at all? If you add a `java -version` *just* before the line running Java, does that show the same version?

Comment: You're right that major.minor 51.0 is compatible with Java 7. So you _have_ to be running with another (lesser) Java.

Comment: Most most likely you are NOT running Java 7. The error message strongly suggests so. If you run it on Linux, use `ls -l /proc/<pid>/exe` to see what's really running.

Comment: You might try downgrading your test environment Hadoop to match the production environment. I'm guessing it will start failing in test.

Comment: Thank you guys.. Let me check and come back on this. One thing i will be trying immediately is to add java -version just before the line running Java.  Adding this in the test environment does show Java 7. Let me try the same in production environment and will respond.

Comment: By the way, do you think there is a  possibility this error might come up if the code was built using open jdk and run in oracle jdk or vice versa ?

Comment: Thank you guys. Turned out the java version being used within the script was actually < 7 , though java version outside the script was 7.